# Can't run Grass7 tools from python qgis

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, grass-gis

I'm trying to run GRASS's v.net.steiner in a python script, but I can't seem to call GRASS tools.

```
from qgis.core import *

qgs = QgsApplication([], False)
qgs.initQgis()

import processing
from processing.core.Processing import Processing
Processing.initialize()

INPUT = mypath
points = pts
OUTPUT = myoutputpath

Roads = QgsVectorLayer(INPUT)
if not Roads.isValid():
    raise Exception("Layer failed to load!")

buffer_output = OUTPUT

alg_params = {
'-g': False,
'GRASS_MIN_AREA_PARAMETER': 0.0001,
'GRASS_OUTPUT_TYPE_PARAMETER': 0,  # auto
'GRASS_REGION_PARAMETER': None,
'GRASS_SNAP_TOLERANCE_PARAMETER': -1,
'GRASS_VECTOR_DSCO': '',
'GRASS_VECTOR_EXPORT_NOCAT': False,
'GRASS_VECTOR_LCO': '',
'acolumn': '',
'arc_type': [0,1], 
'input': Roads,
'npoints': -1,
'points': points,
'terminal_cats':'1-100000',
'threshold': 50,
'output': OUTPUT
}
result = processing.run('v.net.steiner', alg_params, is_child_algorithm=True)
result_layer = result['OUTPUT']

qgs.exitQgis()
```

I get the following error:

grass:v.net not found in python script